# Histograms and Density Plots do not match up

Tags: r, histogram, kernel-density

I am creating histograms of substitutions: 1st, 2nd,or 3rd sub over Time. So each histogram shows the number of subs in a given minute given the Sub Number. The histograms make sense to me because for the most part they are smooth (I used a bin width of 1 minute). Nothing looks too out of the ordinary. However, when I overlay a density plot, the tails on the left inflate and I cannot determine why for one of the graphs.

The dataset is of substitions, ranging from minute 1 to a maximum time. I then cut this dataset in half to only look at when the sub was made after minute 45. I have not folded this data back and I have tried to create a reproducable example, but cannot given the data.

Code used to create in R

```
## Filter out subs that are not in the second half
df.half<-df[df$PeriodId>=2,]
p<-ggplot(data=df.half, aes(x=time)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),position="identity", alpha=0.5,binwidth=1)+
  geom_vline(data=sumy.df.half,aes(xintercept=grp.mean),color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=1)+
  geom_density(alpha=.2)+
  facet_grid(SUB_NUMBER ~ .)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.075),breaks = c(seq(0,0.075,0.025)),
                     minor_breaks = c(seq(0,0.075,0.025)),name='Count')
p
```

Why, for the First Sub is the density plot inflated in the tail if there are no values less than 45? Also why isn't the density plot more inflated in the tail for the Second Sub?

Side Note: I did ask this question on crossvalidated, but was told since it involved R, to ask it here instead. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401858/histograms-and-density-plot-do-not-match-up)

[image]

So I was able to change the code and get the following:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data=df.half, aes(x=time,y=..density..),position="identity", alpha=0.5,binwidth=1)+
  geom_density(data=df.half,aes(x=time,y=..density..))+
  geom_vline(data=sumy.df.half,aes(xintercept=grp.mean),color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=1)+
  facet_grid(SUB_NUMBER ~ .)
```

[image]

This looks more correct and at least now fits the dataset. However, I am still confused as to why those issues occured in the first place.

Comment: Will the error persist if you move the codeline specifying the density just after the `geom_histogram`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no data sample to reproduce the error, you *could* try to 
make sure that the environment used by `geom_density` is correct by specifying it explicitly. You can also try to move the code line specifying the density (`geom_density`) just after the `geom_histogram`. Also, the *y*-axis label is probably wrong - it is now set as *counts*, while values suggest that is in fact *density*.

*How would I specify density explicitly?*

You can specify the density parameters explicitly by specifying `data`, `aes` and `position` directly in `geom_density` function call, so it would use these stated instead of inherited arguments:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data=df.half, aes(x=time,y=..density..),position="identity", alpha=0.5,binwidth=1)+
  geom_density(data=df.half,aes(x=time,y=..density..))+
  geom_vline(data=sumy.df.half,aes(xintercept=grp.mean),color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=1)+
  facet_grid(SUB_NUMBER ~ .)
```

*I do not understand how it occured in the first place*
I think in your initial code for `geom_density`, you have explicitly specified just the `alpha` argument. Thus for all of the rest of the parameters it needed, (`data`, `aes`, `position` etc) it used the inherited arguments/parameters and apparently it did not inherit them correctly. Probably it tried to use the data argument from the `geom_vline` function - `sumy.df.half` , or was confused by the  syntaxis in argument "..density.."

Comment: How would I specify density explicitly?

Comment: by specifying `data`, `aes`  and `position` directly in function call, so it would use these stated instead of inherited arguments (cause I am not sure that it is using inherited parameters correctly)

Comment: What do you mean specify them directly in funciton call?

Comment: I mean in code line in which you specify the geom_density parameters - `geom_density()`. Now you explicitly specify just the `alpha`.

Comment: I think so. I added new code and the new plot above. It makes more sense, but I do not understand how it occured in the first place.

Comment: @JackArmstrong Cool. I added some explanation to the answer.